# Updating a column with a row number

Tags: teradata, rowcount

I have a large table and need to add row numbers to it in Teradata. I have a column on the table already called row_num but I need to update it with the actual number. I've tried to use the below code but it won't work.

```
update database.time
set row_num = INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
(START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
NO CYCLE))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: How large is *a large table*?

Comment: The table is ~4b records

Comment: Why do you want to assign a sequence number to that table?

Answer (score 1):

```
update  t

from    mytable t 
      ,(select     t.*
                   ,cast( row_number() over (order by id) as bigint) as rn

        from        mytable t
        ) tt

set     row_num = tt.rn

where   t.id = tt.id
;
```

Comment: P.s. - @dnoeth is going to suggest that for a big table you'll use CTAS instead of UPDATE, which is totally right.

Comment: And when Kristen runs the query it will fail with a Numeric Overflow because ROW_NUMBER returns an Int by default. But this would happen for the original update, too :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - Not necessarily, depends on version and configuration :-) Just to be on the safe side - I added a CAST to the answer

Comment: Can you explain your answer please instead of just giving SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an identity column that uniquely identifies each row, you can do:

```
update t
    set t.row_num = tt.seqnum
    from database.time t,
         (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from database.time t
         ) tt
    where t.id = tt.id;
```

Comment: This is not Teradata syntax